# How to manage uploading operations one by one

Tags: php, ios, mysql, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to send certain data from iOS to online MySQL database. PHP is used on the server to handle the data receiving and inserting.

The thing is that I have several data packages. And the key is to send them one by one, which means I need a mechanism to let the second data package in the queue wait until iOS received feedback from the server confirming the first set of data has already been stored into the database.

I initially tried creating a serial dispatch queue, aiming to have the iOS app execute uploading work in a sequence. Although iOS side did carry out the work according to the sequence, but each task simply "finished" at sending out its data package without waiting to see if the data have been inserted into the database. Then the problem is there will always be some time lapse between sending out the data and data being fully saved to MySQL in the server, due to issues like network connection.

So the result is the data may not be saved in desired sequence, with some later data may be saved earlier than the previous data.

I'm guess what is missing is a "feedback" mechanism from the server side to the iOS side.

Can anybody suggest a way to realize this feedback mechanism, so I can control the serial sequence of uploading data tasks.

Thank you very much!

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending data to server then most of available frameworks offers callback. With AFNetworking (or now known as Almofire) it would look like this:

```
[[ConnectionManager instance] GET: @"link" parameters: nil
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject)
{
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error)
{
}];
```

So you can put your code in given handlers and continuously make requests.

You may also want to create concurrent Operations and put those on OperationQueue while setting proper dependencies but it's surely more time consuming.